# String Message Staring with bullet-in needs to in the nextLine

Tags: java, regex, string

I had string message,which contains message like below.

Here im trying to spilt the message when the line starts with number followed by .(full stop)

```
String str="1. Hi this is test 2. this is also test 3. this is also test 4. this
is also test 5. this is also test";
```

Want the output like

```
1.Hi this is test
2. this is also test
3. this is also test
4. this is also test
5. this is also test
```

Tried many ways. But no luck

Comment: could you show us atleast one of the "many" ways tried by you?

Comment: Pattern.compile(".*\\D.*");

Comment: .matches any character. you need to escape it (using \\ or use Pattern.quote() ). Also \\D means NOT a DIGIT . are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

```
String str="1. Hi this is test 2. this is also test 3. this is also test 4. this is also test 5. this is also test";

for(String s : str.split("(?=\\d.)")) {
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
String str="1. Hi this is test 2. this is also test 3. this is also test 4. this
is also test 5. this is also test";

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[\\d]+\\.[a-z ]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(str);
```